# How to wrap nginx + passenger with custom command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I need to start my rails server like that:

```
DISPLAY=localhost:1.0 xvfb-run bundle exec rails s
```

That does what I need, but I want to use nginx + passenger, where I should put that so it will work? Into `nginx` init script? To the `nginx.conf`? Or somewhere else? I can't find anything in [docs](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html), so how it should be done right?

Answer (score 0):

Install passenger: `gem install passenger`

Install nginx: `rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module` and follow the prompts. Just hit enter to provide the default value

Edit your nginx.conf file:

```
http {
    passenger_root /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/passenger-4.0.30;
    passenger_ruby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p353/ruby;
    ...
    ...
    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    passenger_enabled on;

    root /path/to/rails/app/public;
    ...
```

Also Comment out:

```
    #location / {
    #    root   html;
    #    index  index.html index.htm;
    #}
```

You will also need to precompile your assets by running

`RAILS_ENV=production rake:assets precompile`

Now you just need to start nginx.

`sudo service nginx start`

If you get an error then you can go the directory where nginx files are located (`/opt/nginx` by default)

Go to the `/opt/nginx/sbin` directory and:

`./nginx` to start nginx

`./nginx -s stop` to stop nginx

You can also add this your $PATH variable

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific, I alreaady have working nginx + passenger, I just want to wrap it somehow with some command. As an side note, on arch linux (my VPS is running on it) threre is no `service`, `systemctl` is used for managing services.